# What is the correct way to update a counter in React

Tags: reactjs, counter, setstate

How do I declare a counter in state, declare other variables that use that counter for output and then update the counter and all other vars on an `onClick`? Is it down to setState being `async`? I have just begun with React.

```
const arr = Object.keys(questionAnswers).map(key => { return questionAnswers[key] });

this.current = 0;

this.state = {
    current: this.current,
    questions: arr[this.current].question,
    options: Object.keys(arr[this.current].options).map(key => { return arr[this.current].options[key]}),
    }
}
```

And then updating with an `onClick` function:

```
nextQuestion = () => {
    this.current++
    this.setState({
    current: arr[this.current].question,
    options: arr[this.current].options
    });
}
```

Comment: My issue is how I then use current to update. For example, this appears not to work: ` this.state = { arr: arr, current: this.current, questions: arr[this.current].question, options: Object.keys(arr[0].options).map(key => { return arr[0].options[key]}), } } nextQuestion = () => { this.setState(prevState => ({ current: prevState.current+1, questions: prevState.arr[prevState.current+1].questions, })) } `

Answer (score 1):

Update counter you can make in the next way:

```
setState((prevState) => {current: prevState.current + 1});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the state as this.state

```
this.state = {
  current: 0
  ...
}
```

```
nextQuestion = () => {
  this.setState({
    current: this.state.current + 1
    ...
  })
}
```

Whenever state is changed, react will trigger a re-render of your component, so can always refer to this.state

Answer (score 0):

The **setState** function is executed in batches and its asynchronous. In your case, if you want to update a variable based on **previous state**, then you should use a **function** within **setState** function. This will give synchronous updates.

Something like this.

```
this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
  current: prevState.current + 1
}));
```